# How can I view reviews by a particular user?

Tags: support, review, profile-page

Occasionally, when reviewing posts on the Stack Exchange sites where I'm active, after indicating an action, I would then go back to see the situation with that post. For example, I would go back and see that I rejected an edit, another user rejected the edit but yet another user approved it.  The edit (in my view) is clearly wrong, so I'm interested to see other reviews by that same user - maybe (just maybe) the user isn't doing something correctly.

Yet, after browsing around the user's profile, I didn't find any way to view the reviews by the user.  I can see the user's edits, but not reviews of others' edits.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the User profile, on the Activity tab, choose "all actions" and filter by "reviews".

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/181154/aleks-g?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Answer (score 6):

Users -> Activity -> All Actions -> Reviews

[Example of my reviews on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2415822/jal?tab=activity&sort=reviews)

[image: Reviews]